# Expression about the output voltage Op amp BJT

Tags: operational-amplifier

Determine the expression of the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffSzm9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(A) \$Vo = \eta \cdot V_T \ln(\frac{I_{C0}R}{V_i})\$

(B) \$Vo = -I_{C0}\cdot R \left[e^{\frac{V_i}{\eta V_T}}-1\right]\$

(C) \$Vo = -I_{C0}\cdot R \left[e^{-\frac{V_i}{\eta V_T}}-1\right]\$

(D) \$Vo = - \eta \cdot V_T \ln(\frac{I_{C0}R}{V_i})\$

**ANSWER C**

I really find the reason why the answer C is correct. How can the output voltage goes to \$ I_{C0}R \$ when the \$Vi\$ increases?

the transistor Q1 isn't on cutoff region?

Please any explanation?

Original picture:
[image]

Comment: Where did you find the circuit (please provide a link if possible)? (I suspect you have the emitter and collector reversed, and there should be non-zero bias on either the BJT base or op-amp non-inverting input)

Comment: It doesn’t look like it’ll do any of the above.

Comment: @ThePhoton it is a facebook question exercise for GATE preparation. I have uploaded the original picture.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you right. Like the The Photon said i think that that transistor is a PNP. the colector base will be short and it acts as normal diode.

Comment: Whatever it is does not look very useful.

Comment: If you assume Vce(sat) can go to 0 V or slightly below while remaining in reverse-active mode, this circuit will give the suggested answer. Possibly the reversal of collector and emitter is intentional if reverse saturation has a lower Vec(sat) than the usual Vce(sat).

Comment: Two things are obvious: (1) When \$V_i\$ is sufficiently below ground, the BJT is saturated and the opamp will rail to its (+) rail; and, (2) When \$V_i\$ is sufficiently away from saturating the BJT, no collector current will flow and therefore the output will be ground (\$0\:\text{V}\$.) So any answer picked will have to arrive towards those two extremes. These will occur with \$-700\:\text{mV}\le V_i\le -500\:\text{mV}\$. In between? The collector current will have an exponentially declining relationship with more positive going \$V_i\$. So this helps a lot in selecting a possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Despite my (and other commentors') skepticism about this circuit, if you believe LTSpice, this circuit actually does work. Here I've tried both the as-drawn circuit and swapping the emitter and collector pins of the BJT.

[image]

[image]

With the BJT reversed (input to the emitter), the gain is substantially increased.

I'd expect this to also give a closer fit to an ideal exponential response, but haven't checked it.

In some other testing I found that the 2N3904 model in LTSpice will pull \$V_{ce}\$ to just 10-50 mV if strongly saturated, much lower than the ~0.2 V we often assume for saturation behavior. The model has essentially the same \$V_{ce}(sat)\$ for both forward and reverse operation. I don't know if this is realistic or a model inaccuracy.

(Also, from the charts given, you can find by inspection which of the 4 suggested answers is closest to the simulator result)

**Now, how to actually solve the problem**

Consider this circuit:

[image]

In this circuit, to maintain the two op-amp inputs at the same voltage, the current through R1 must be equal to \$I_1\$, and therefore

$$V_{out} = -R_1 I_1$$

The circuit you're asked to analyze essentially is an initial nonlinear voltage to current converter, followed by this linear current to voltage converter.

So if you can work out what will be the voltage-to-current transfer function of the transistor circuit on the input, you can work out the overall transfer function by multiplying by \$-R_1\$.

Comment: I am really suprise with your models simulation. I cant imagine that the outputs are almost the same behavior.

Comment: @miguel747, remember that the BJT is more-or-less a symmetric device. It works in reverse on exactly the same principles as it does in forward operation. It's only the optimization of the doping profiles, etc, that makes the operation less efficient in reverse.